# json_encode in PHP is not returning any results

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

I have a PHP script that is retrieving some data from my database, and I want to encode it in json for processing in my Android app. I want the results to be like this:

```
{
    "part": [
        {
            "partNo": "value",
            "partName": "value",
            "shortDesc": "value",
            "longDesc": "value",
            "image": "value"
        },
        {
            "partNo": "value",
            "partName": "value",
            "shortDesc": "value",
            "longDesc": "value",
            "image": "value"
        }
    ],
    "success": 1
}
```

I am using the following PHP script.

```
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// execute query based on specified user input
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

// check to see if results were found
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    //create a part array in $response to hold the part details
    $response['part'] = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        //create an array for the part details
        $part = array();
        $part['partNo'] = $row['partNo'];
        $part['partName'] = $row['partName'];
        $part['shortDesc'] = $row['shortDesc'];
        $part['longDesc'] = $row['longDesc'];
        $part['image'] = "data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['image']);

        // put the array results for a single part in $response
        array_push($response['part'], $part);
    }
    // add the code for success to $response
    $response['code'] = 1;

    // and send it in json
    echo(json_encode($response));
    //print_r($response);
    //print_r(json_encode($response));
} else {
        //no results found
        $response['code'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = "No part found!";
        echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

I am not getting any response with `echo (json_encode($response));` or `print_r(json_encode($response));`. But when I do `print_r($response);`, I am getting a response!

```
Array ( [part] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [partNo] => value [partName] => value [shortDesc] => value [longDesc] => value [image] => data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAAS.../9k= ) ) [code] => 1 )
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? Why is it not working with json_encode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use to return the `$response` in json format:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: No good, it's still the same. Only `print_r($response)` is giving me a response.

Comment: It kinda worked, but now I am getting null values everywhere!

`{"part":[{"partNo":null,"partName":null,"shortDesc":null,"longDesc":null}],"code":1}Array
(
    [part] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [partNo] => 
                    [partName] => 
                    [shortDesc] => 
                    [longDesc] => 
                )

        )

    [code] => 1
)`

I also did some testing by supplying a non-existent partNo (to double check), and the unsuccessful else block is executed as intended with the proper json response.

Comment: maybe they just are null values ?

Comment: No, they do contain values. It's strange though; now even the print_r(response) that was printing out the values previously is giving me null values.

Comment: @MephasmVortex that is because you are using mysql_fetch_array and not mysql_fetch_assoc this line of code is in the while( .... ) condition

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was trying out `mysql_fetch_row`, that's why I had null values! Changed it back to `mysql_fetch_array` and it worked! Thanks for the help :)